# UnitTest: Cannot take whole Blob value from return value for System.assertequals

Tags: unit-test, blob

I have a class that I want to do unit_test, which returns Blob value above 3000byte.
Regarding this, I want to compare it with expected value, using toString method.

However, I can't get the whole value... always come in short of some letters or byte at the end.
It does not matter whether I am getting the value of string or blob.

How can I get whole value?

Unit test( is working but not getting the full value of test )

```
Blob test = response.responseBody;
System.assertEquals(expectedBlob.toString(), test.toString()); 
System.assertEquals('last12letters',test.toString().substringAfter('justbeforeThe12letters = ').substring(0,10));
```

expectedBlob.toString

> ??;;.abchowareyoutoday_givemewholevalue_justbeforeThe12letters_last12letters

test.toString

> ??;;.abchowareyoutoday_givemewholevalue_justbeforeThe12letters_las12l

Like this returned version of Blob has some letters in luck.
This is almost all some letters at the last and
some wrongly cut around the end as well.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to be able to help you. You should [edit] your question to include more details. Sharing the relevant bits of code is important. In this case, knowing what value you expect in your test, the value you're actually getting, and how the two are different is also likely important. About the only thing I think anyone can tell you as-is is that if you're getting your blob from, say, `ContentVersion`, then it is base64 encoded.

Comment: Derek F That is so true. Thank you for your advise,.
I just added some more info to this. If you are still here. Is there anyway I do not have to change encode??

Comment: How are you generating this blob data?

Comment: Thanks David for responding! I do not think this is occurring because of generation process since that Blob is playing its role properly and  google console says so.

Comment: @DerekF Sorry I forgot to mention you.